# Why can't you pass List (NOT ArrayList) between activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

As far as I understand, there is no way to pass a simple `List` object between Activities without the `List` being an `ArrayList`.  Am I perhaps missing some way to do this?  If not, does anyone know why Google would force users to use implementation specific details in their code?

Comment: I don't know, but I am betting because for large arrays, it's way more efficient to do a block memory copy than it is to create a whole new datastructure of let's say a linked list and copy each individual object over.

Comment: I agree w/ Greg.. they've probably optimized that particular implementation

Comment: @RhinoFeeder sorry misread the post. deleted my previous comment

Comment: Its probably worth noting as another reply said below, you might be doing it wrong.  Have you considered using an Application-wide list that's accessible from other parts of the program directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass explicit implementations because they implement Serializable, while their abstract and interfaces do not.

List, and other collections, are not Serializable because that is not their definition. They offer the choice to their implementations, since you also have implementations of List that are not Serializable.

This is important to have, since you might want to save data which is not save for serialization, in a list. In those cases, you can choose implementations which are a better choice for this data, instead of being forced by 'List' to be able to serialize.

Comment: That third paragraph is really where the meat is for me on this topic.  It makes sense then.  So because of the nature of how we are handling this object in Android, we NEED a `Serializable`, which means we need to invoke an implementation of `List` ?

Comment: Exactly. You need Serializable (or Parcable, please use that for your own objects) in order to pass an object from Activity to Activity, since this is not possible by reference. Serializable is only implemented on specific implementations, not on interfaces/abstracts. This, because a List is simply not always desired to be serializable. The what and why on both these requirements will probably have extended explanations all over the internet so you should read up on those.

Comment: Sounds awesome, so one last quick question.  Would it be acceptable/good practice to do this?

    //Driver implements parcelable
    List<Driver> drivers;

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out){
        outstate.putParcelableArrayList(KEY, new ArrayList<Driver>(drivers));
    }

Comment: Should work fine, but don't know if there is any reason to keep using the interface `List` if you're gonna have to use an implementation later on anyway. Probably best to just pick the best implementation from the start and stick with it. Programming against an interface is a best practice, but often just not practical. 
If you really want to keep using interfaces for some reason, you could consider to just get your data between Activities in a different way. Per example, you can just persist the data in a database and fetch them again when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class that you can use to store references of things like these and more.